# UIImage disappears when trying to add a layer mask

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, mask

I have created this function to round specific corners on a `UIImageView`:

```
func roundCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner], imageView: UIImageView) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: imageView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 7.0, height: 7.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = imageView.frame
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    return maskLayer
}
```

When I apply it to the image `topLeftImage` like this: `topLeftImage.layer.mask = roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft], imageView: topLeftImage)`, it makes the image disappear. Here is how I declare the image:

```
let topLeftImage: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "myImage")
    iv.layoutIfNeeded()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()
```

How can I apply a layer mask and still have the image appear on the screen.

Comment: add lazy var instead of using let

Comment: unrelated but your method always round the same corner i think you need change `let maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: imageView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 7.0, height: 7.0))`by `let maskPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: imageView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 7.0, height: 7.0))` if you really want your method works using defined parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the image isn't appearing in the screen because you aren't initializing UIImageView with frame. Try the following code snippet:

```
let iv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
```